# Can an ASP.NET HttpHandler handle an http 400 - Bad Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis-7, httphandler

We have an HttpHandler that deals directly with binary posts over HTTP from custom client software. The client software occasionally sends data which results in IIS 7 responding with a 400 - Bad Request. Since the "400 Bad Request" is special in that HTTP.SYS transparently handles it in kernel mode without notifying user mode of anything, no errors are raised to be handled in ASP.NET. Is it possible to catch this http 400 in ASP.NET, so that I can write specific data to the Response stream in these scenarios? A redirect to another page isn't an option as it needs to be in the current Request/Response.

Comment: If this question was "put your favorite HTTP.SYS and http 400 jokes here" it would be answered by at least 238 respondents by now.

Comment: Are you running in IIS7's integrated pipeline mode or classic mode? I'm not sure, but you *might* be able to see the error when using integrated mode since "everything" goes through the ASP.NET pipeline. In classic mode I think you're SOL. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what is causing the 400, then you may be able to customise the behaviour of http.sys via the registry to deal with it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129

However, you should be aware that there are potential security and performance ramifications of doing this.

Another option would be to use a filtering proxy before IIS, thereby capturing the request before it goes any further.

Comment: The error is from an invalid content length header, which according to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786188.aspx 
can't be customized. It looks like it may not be possible without basically writing your own http server at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I would instead ask them to fix the custom client software.  Give them a report showing the failed requests.  If you are able to, run a sniffer such as Wireshark and send them the packets if they do not believe the problem is with their software.

Answer (score 1):

If your custom client causes IIS to trigger HTTP 400, it's probably flawed and is not submitting valid HTTP requests according to the standard. If you can alter the client, it would be the right thing to do. Otherwise, what you're working with is not HTTP, and IIS is designed to handle HTTP requests. Therefore, you should run a custom server for your own protocol (which is a non-standard HTTP like thing).

It's not advised to use IIS/ASP.NET to handle such a request as it might cause some weird unexpected things to happen.

Comment: The error is due to an invalid content length header from a corrupt payload. Changing the client software isn't an option and I just need to send down a customized http response to inform the client to clear it's payload, but there is no way for me to trap the 400 error and send the client anything.

Comment: Whatever it is, what you need is a server that handles the non-standard protocol (= standard with implementation bugs). You should probably write a custom server that handles this issue. I think Dave R.'s proxy filtering solution is the best idea. Any solution is an ugly hack nevertheless.